# What does it mean for a probability model to be "well-specified" or "misspecified"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I read in several articles that a model $\{p_\theta , \theta \in \Theta\}$ is **well-specified** if there exists a $\theta^* \in \Theta$ such that $p_{\theta^*} = p^*$.

Similarly, a model $\{p_\theta , \theta \in \Theta\}$ is **misspecified** if there **does not** exists a $\theta^* \in \Theta$ such that $p_{\theta^*} = p^*$.

Here, the definition of $p^*$ is that it is the true "data-generating distribution".

I can understand the terminology but what is the underlying logic here? I feel that I am missing the deeper story here. What is an example of a misspecified model? thanks!

Comment: If your model is misspecified, then you'll never learn the true data-generating distribution no matter how many examples you see. A simple example is if your model is that your data is being generated by a linear function with some parameters but in fact it is not linear at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Well-specified* means that the class of distribution $\mathcal{C}$ you are **assuming** for your modeling *actually* contains the unknown probability distribution $p$ from where the sample is drawn.

*Misspecified* means, on the other hand,  that $\mathcal{C}$ does **not** contain $p$. You made a modeling assumption, and it is not perfect: for instance, you assume your sample is Gaussian, but (maybe due to noise, or just inherently) it is not actually originating from any Gaussian distribution. It may be *close* to some Gaussian, if you're lucky, but not exactly.

For instance, many papers dealing with learning the structure of data (think of social sciences, biology, physics) may assume some underlying structure: "the data is coming from some multidimensional Gaussian," or "the different coordinates are independent (product distribution)." This is a modelling assumption which simplifies a lot and typically avoids intractability or impossibility to reasonably analyze the data; but it's most likely only an approximation of the real, actual data. This is what a misspecified model is: a convenient (or even necessary) *assumption* on the distribution underlying the data, which may only be a reasonable *approximation*.